# Cannot use subversion and access my website at the same time

Tags: linux, nginx, amazon-ec2, svn

I install svn follow this [5 minutes to set up a subversion server in the cloud](http://www.ange-agostini.com/blog/it/5-minutes-to-set-up-a-subversion-server-in-the-cloud.html)

everything fine until this command `sudo service httpd restart` 
it said some process already bind port 80

```
Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
                                                           [FAILED]
```

so I use `netstat -lpn | grep :80` to see and found `nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`  that bind port 80

then I kill that process and use command `sudo service httpd restart` 
everything seem fine I can use svn properly.

**But I am wrong!** 
svn work fine but I can't access my website and sub-domain all my sub-domain went to `/var/www/html` and then I try `sudo service nginx restart`  I got the same problem as before port 80 is already bind and If I kill process that bind to port 80 and restart nginx  svn will go down (404 Not Found) and my website will available again

please help. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your website is configured to be served by nginx, and your svn repo is configured to be served by apache/httpd. You need to pick a single web server and stick with it -- bring the configuration for svn over to nginx or your website config over to apache/httpd.

Here's a howto for setting up svn under nginx: http://www.thatsgeeky.com/2011/03/setting-up-subversion/

Comment: thank so much I have done many things with your suggest and now it work!! thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can run subversion on some other port (8080, for example) and proxy it via nginx.